# Troubles using scrapy with javascript __doPostBack method

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, scrapy, dopostback

Trying to automatically grab the search results from a public search, but running into some trouble. The URL is of the form

```
http://www.website.com/search.aspx?keyword=#&&page=1&sort=Sorting
```

As I click through the pages, after visiting this page, it changes slightly to

```
http://www.website.com/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Sorting&page=2
```

Problem being, if I then try to directly visit the second link without first visiting the first link, I am redirected to the first link. My current attempt at this is defining a long list of start_urls in scrapy.

```
class websiteSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "website"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    baseUrl = "http://www.website.com/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Sorting&page="
    start_urls = [(baseUrl+str(i)) for i in range(1,1000)]
```

Currently this code simply ends up visiting the first page over and over again. I feel like this is probably straightforward, but I don't quite know how to get around this.

UPDATE:
Made some progress investigating this and found that the site updates each page by sending a POST request to the previous page using __doPostBack(arg1, arg2). My question now is how exactly do I mimic this POST request using scrapy. I know how to make a POST request, but not exactly how to pass it the arguments I want.

SECOND UPDATE:
I've been making a lot of progress! I think... I looked through examples and documentation and eventually slapped together this version of what I think should do the trick:

```
def start_requests(self):
    baseUrl = "http://www.website.com/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Sorting&page="
    target = 'ctl00$empcnt$ucResults$pagination'
    requests = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        url = baseUrl + str(i)
        argument = str(i+1)
        data = {'__EVENTTARGET': target, '__EVENTARGUMENT': argument}
        currentPage = FormRequest(url, data)
        requests.append(currentPage)
    return requests
```

The idea is that this treats the POST request just like a form and updates accordingly. However, when I actually try to run this I get the following traceback(s) (Condensed for brevity):

```
2013-03-22 04:03:03-0400 [guru] ERROR: Unhandled error on engine.crawl()
dfd.addCallbacks(request.callback or spider.parse, request.errback)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 280, in addCallbacks
        assert callable(callback)
    exceptions.AssertionError: 

2013-03-22 04:03:03-0400 [-] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-03-22 04:03:03-0400 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest: Skipped (request already seen)
```

Changing question to be more directed at what this post has turned into.

Thoughts?

P.S. When the second errors happen scrapy is unable to cleany shutdown and I have to send a SIGINT twice to get things to actually wrap up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormRequest` doesn't have a positional argument in the constructor for `formdata`:

```
class FormRequest(Request):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formdata = kwargs.pop('formdata', None)
```

so you actually have to say `formdata=`:

```
requests.append(FormRequest(url, formdata=data))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, but there is a deeper problem still. It now returns 404 errors uniformly. Any ideas?

Comment: 404 means the server thinks the url is wrong, so what is the actual url? Usually if the POST data is wrong the server will give a 500-ish error, usually. Btw: You just bumped me up over the 1k mark, nice.

Comment: Also if you are dealing with .aspx, you may need to include the giant __VIEWSATE in the POST data as well.

Comment: the site is guru.com, and the really weird thing is that the responses I get to the post are a weird combination of 404 errors and 200 codes that give a response body of a 500 error.

Comment: Realized this is probably a different question at this point, so will re ask the relevant part and mark this accepted.